# Send/retrive RAW ethernet frames (ARP request) in objective-C on OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, sockets, ethernet

is it possible to send/retrive ARP frames in Objective-C ?

I want to check avaiability of several devices in the local network from the code by ARP requests.

I think that it is only way to do that because the ICMP may be diabled, and not all of the devices has bonjure instaled.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go for it.  Anything you can do in C, you can do in Objective-C.

Comment: I'm unable to open socket in RAW mode on BSD-like system (OSX). I found walk around by using /dev/bfp device but it requires root piviliges.